# Visual Studio 2013 crash when I'm trying to compile Eigen

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, crash, eigen

The following simplified code:

```
#include "Eigen/Core"

template <int n>
Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, n> init_array(float a)
{
    Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, n> res;
    res.fill(a);
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, 3> a = init_array<3>(1.0f);
}
```

leads to the Visual Studio crash:

```
main.cpp(13): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
   (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1325)
   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
```

I downloaded the latest version of Eigen 3.2.5.
I have the Visual Studio Professional 2013 Version 12.0.21005.1.

Does anybody know a workaround?

Comment: Does `#include "Eigen\Core"` actually work on Windows ? For portability at least it should be `#include "Eigen/Core"`

Comment: It does. If I change code a bit (for example remove the function's parameter `float a`), everything works well.

Comment: Not that this will help much, but your posted code (sry, I had to change the include stmt, that backslash just felt dirty) works on VS2010, CL version:  16.00.40219.01.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem. Apparently, you should update your Visual Studio 2013. This worked for me.
This problem [was reported to Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/813571/vs2013-compiler-crash-with-eigen-and-template-functions) and they fix it in the update 2 (current is 5)